# Converting a datetime to local time based on timezone in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question related to dates and time in Python.

**Problem:**

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(row[1]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
localtime = date.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Brussels"))
formattedDate = localtime.strftime("%Y-%m%-%d")
```

1. In the code above, `str(row[1])` gives back a UTC datetime coming from a mysql database: `2022-02-28 23:00:00`
2. I parse this as a datetime and change the timezone to Europe/Brussels.
3. I then format it back to a string.

**Expected result:**

I'd like to return the date in local time. Europe/Brussels adds one hour so I would expect that strftime returns `2022-03-01`, but it keeps returning `2022-02-28`.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Why the `str()` around `row[1]`? Isn't it already a string? If not, what is it? Is it perhaps already a `date` or `datetime` object…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` is a *naïve* date, without timezone, because no timezone information was in the string you parsed. Using `astimezone` on that simply attaches timezone information to it, turning a naïve date into an aware one. It obviously can't convert any times, because it doesn't know what to convert *from*.

This also already contains the answer: make the `date` aware that it's in UTC first before trying to convert it to a different timezone:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(...).astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see!

I ended up doing this, basically the same as you mentioned:

```
from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
to_zone = tz.gettz('Europe/Brussels')
utcdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(row[1]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
utcdate = utcdate.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
localdate = utcdate.astimezone(to_zone)
formattedLocalDate = localdate.strftime("%Y%m%d");
```

The *naïve* date gets UTC aware by the utcdate.replace(tzinfo=from_zone).

Thanks for helping!